# Why is NonlinearModelFit not working?

Tags: fitting

I have a set of x,y-values

```
data = {{522.9, 1.3}, {524.4, 1.5}, {525.9, 1.5}, {527.9, 2}, {529.8, 1.9}, 
{531.6, 1.8}, {533.4, 1.8}, {535.2, 1.8}, {537.4, 2.2}, {539.6, 2.2}, 
{541.8, 2.2}, {543.8, 2}, {546.1, 2.3}, {548.8, 2.7}, {551.4, 2.6}, 
{553.8, 2.4}, {556.5, 2.7}, {560, 3.5}, {562.9, 2.9}, {565.8, 2.9}, 
{569, 3.2}, {572.2, 3.2}, {575.2, 3}, {578.9, 3.7}, {582.2, 3.3}, 
{585.4, 3.2}, {589.4, 4}, {592.9, 3.5}, {596.7, 3.8}}
```

and want to fit it with a function of the form $$f(x)=\Big(\frac{x-a}{b}\Big)^c,a<522,b>0,0<c<1\,.$$ So I used

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {((x - a)/b)^c, a < 522, b > 0, c < 1, c > 0}, 
                        {a, b, c}, x]
```

but that gives me $a=-238173$, $b=1$ and $c=7.67666\cdot 10^{-10}$. Plotted it looks like

[image: Plot of data and Fit]

with data as dots and the fit as straight line. It does not look like a real fit.

Why does it look like that and how can I get a 'real' fit?

Comment: Also probably better if you work with the log of this function (and of the data y-values)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give the algorithm better initial guesses:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {((x - a)/b)^c, a < 522, b > 0, c < 1, c > 0}, 
                       {{a, 520}, {b, 10}, {c, 1}}, x]

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 520, 600}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a -> 510.396, b -> 6.47687, c -> 0.51387} *)
```

Comment: Actually, setting this starting value for `a` alone suffices in this case.

Comment: This looks really good, thank you! But why should it be necessary to specify the parameters more clearly?

Comment: @zhenvy The fitting process may end up stuck in a local optimum.

Comment: @zhenvy Linear models have a special property that allows you to find the "right" answer. For nonlinear models, there's no way to write a program that is guaranteed to always work. Instead, we can only try hard to find an optimal solution. Sometime you have to help it out by giving it a hint of some kind.

Comment: @zhenvy, anytime nonlinear functions are involved in a numerical effort, whether solving equations or fitting models, the numerical methods involved always need a starting guess to get them running, so supplying the best guess that you can give is your responsibility.

Comment: @zhenvy Another reason in this case for the starting values needing to be closer to the final values is that the model is a bit overparameterized for the data.  If you look at `nlm["CorrelationMatrix"]`, you'll find that all 3 parameter estimators are highly correlated with each other:  `{{1., -0.979146, -0.962351}, {-0.979146, 1., 0.996106}, {-0.962351, 
  0.996106, 1.}}`.